# Add Organization info to Google Contacts API

Tags: python, google-api-python-client

I have the contact API working with Google, so for example:

```
contact = gdata.contacts.data.ContactEntry()
contact.name = gdata.data.Name(given_name=gdata.data.GivenName(text='Frank'),
family_name=gdata.data.FamilyName(text='Something'))
```

However I need to add organization and title to the contact, and the documentation is pretty sparse; I tried this with no success:

```
contact.organization=gdata.data.Organization(name='My Company',title='Chief Fun Officer')
```

That command works, however when I execute:

```
client.CreateContact(contact,feed)
```

It fails with:

> AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '_become_child'

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

This is the correct way of adding organization details:

```
contact.organization= gdata.data.Organization(name=gdata.data.OrgName(text='My Company'), title=gdata.data.OrgTitle(text='Chief Fun Officer'), rel=gdata.data.WORK_REL)
```