# How to add JobTitle and Company details in Google Contacts?

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, gdata, google-contacts-api

I am adding contacts to Gmail Accounts using GData. I can add all the details successfully but I don't know how to pass the details of the Company Name and Job Title. I have tried several methods but still can't get it to work correctly.

I have tried the following code but it throws the following error: "Additional information: Execution of request failed:" https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full"

```
            Organization objCompany = new Organization();
            objCompany.Title = "Developer";
            objCompany.Name = "ABC Company";
            newEntry.Organizations.Add(objCompany);
```

If I comment out the above code, everything works perfectly. Please let me know what I'm missing.

Comment: I think your code has issue. I am not familiar with C#, You can check this link https://developers.google.com/gdata/javadoc/com/google/gdata/data/extensions/OrgName for class dependacies. You should give Organization(OrgName(),OrgTitle()). check the constructors in the above link. You can also check this link for reference which has python code.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30624569/add-organization-info-to-google-contacts-api

Comment: Yeah! it's working fine now. Thank you.